# ActionScript 3 - Adjusting speed of math.Random?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've just started learning AS3.

I made this small game, where's some stars spawning to random cordinates at the background,
I made it to random the cordinates, so it spawns the stars to a different place everytime,
but now it is too fast:

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movestar);

Mouse.hide();

function movestar(e:Event)
{
star1.x++
star2.x++
star3.x++
star4.x++
star5.x++
star6.x++
star7.x++
star8.x++
star9.x++

star1.x = Math.random()*550;
star2.x = Math.random()*550;
star3.x = Math.random()*550;
star4.x = Math.random()*550;
star5.x = Math.random()*550;
star6.x = Math.random()*550;
star7.x = Math.random()*550;
star8.x = Math.random()*550;
star9.x = Math.random()*550;

star1.y = Math.random()*400;
star2.y = Math.random()*400;
star3.y = Math.random()*400;
star4.y = Math.random()*400;
star5.y = Math.random()*400;
star6.y = Math.random()*400;
star7.y = Math.random()*400;
star8.y = Math.random()*400;
star9.y = Math.random()*400;
 }
```

Is there a way I can adjust the speed of the stars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but now it is too fast

Fast? Every frame you are giving them new coordinates, and offset them on 1 pixel...

Here's a snippet for you, where I created pseudo stars (dark circles), scattered them randomly and  give them linear movement to the left side of the screen:

```
//Create stars for testing
var stars:Array = createStars(30);
trace(stars);
//Scatter them
scatterObjects(stars, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
//Move them with some speed
var speed:Number = 0.5;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    var i:uint, len:uint = stars.length, star:DisplayObject;

    for (i; i < len; ++i) {
        star = stars[i];
        star.x -= speed;
        if (star.x < 0) {
            star.x = stage.stageWidth;
        }
    }
}

function scatterObjects(list:Array, width:int, height:int):void {
    var star:DisplayObject, i:uint, len:uint = list.length;

    for (i; i < len; ++i) {
        star = list[i];
        star.x = width * Math.random();
        star.y = height * Math.random();
        addChild(star);
    }
}

function createStars(count:uint):Array {
    var result:Array = [], star:Shape, i:uint;
    for (i; i < count; ++i) {
        star = new Shape();
        star.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
        star.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 5);
        result[i] = star;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could add some more comments explaining the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think its misleading to say you are "moving" the stars because it looks like you are just randomly placing the starts on each frame in an area 550 x 400.

Why are you incrementing x in each enter frame event?

Anyways, if you want to slow down the "motion" of the stars, add a counter to moveStar, something like this:

```
counter++;
if(counter<3){
 return;
}
counter=0;
```

This will then update your stars every third frame. You could use a timer instead and update after n milliseconds which would be more accurate when the game runs at different rates on different computation devices.